# Is it safe to remove this plywood ceiling and ceiling joists?

Tags: ceiling, joists, porch

I'm looking to remove the plywood ceiling in this porch along with the ceiling joists that I believe are only serving to hold the ceiling in place. I'm wondering if I'm missing anything.

[image: Porch interior]

The roof is uniformly gabled from front to back.

[image: exterior gable end]

The porch has a 7' ceiling, the main room has a 12' ceiling that is to the gable / \ and the back bedrooms have 8' ceilings with an attic above with an access hatch. So, in sum, it seems there is a "void" above the porch plywood ceiling that doesn't have access and isn't serving any purpose.

[image: Vaulted ceiling in another room]

I drilled a small hole and took a look up there with a USB camera. Looks to be uninsulated and up to the roof plywood. I can see the metal roof roofing nails coming through. The walls are bare studs.

The plan would be to pull down the plywood, pull down the ceiling joists (if that is possible, otherwise leave them exposed) and do the walls in tongue and groove to match the interior room. I might also spray in some insulation in the wall bays as I go.

[image: room with vaulted ceiling looking toward porch in question]

Am I missing anything?

How can I tell if the ceiling joists can come down without issue?

**Edit (9/5/2021):** Hey all, thanks for your help. I pulled down some plywood and this is what it looks like up there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QI0J.jpg

Comment: Well asked question and a nice looking place! I embedded the pics to make it easier for everyone to see them (the site will upload & host them for you, for future reference). Please review to make sure that the spacing and wording still makes sense, and make additional [edit]s if you feel it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much, sorry for the extra work!

Comment: No worries! I'm not sure if a brand new user can embed that many images, so someone may have had to do it for you anyway.

Comment: I would not touch it until cleared by a structural engineer. I highly suspect the joists are required to tie the 3 surrounding lightly built walls that having windows in the way of vertical studs. If you take away the ceiling and the joists, you might find you need to do something about the walls.

Comment: Which direction to the ceiling joists run in this porch? Is it the short direction, between the two walls we can see on the left/right, or is it the long direction between the wall we can see and the one behind the photographer?

Comment: I'll be pulling down at least the plywood when I'm up there next (tomorrow or the following day) and will follow up. I think they run the long direction based on my little peephole experiment, but will confirm.

Comment: Yeah, if they run the long way, there's a _strong_ possibility that they're structural. If they run the short way, they're likely there just to support the plywood. Dimensions probably matter too, especially if they're short.

Comment: `I believe are only serving to hold the ceiling in place` ... it is safer to disbelieve until proven otherwise

Comment: Looks like they run the long way. I'm guessing the blocking running the short way between the joists are not structural and are a later addition.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with @r13  . Joists almost always are necessary to stop the roof from pushing the walls outward.  If you dislike them, consider "scissors joists" which tie the walls to the roof joists on the opposite side of the peak. This gives you a slightly lower cathedral ceiling but eliminates the joists/beams running in mid-air.

Comment: Alternatively, leave the joists but dress them up, or (with SE approval) remove some joists but beef up the remainders to take the strain. Take a "bug" and turn it into a "feature"!

Comment: @FreeMan, Ha, I read that as "StackExchange approval", but I'm sure you mean structural engineer.

Comment: heh... yeah. I read that as I typed it, but decided to leave it. Your interpretation of my _actual_ meaning is correct.

Comment: Updated with a new album. Looks like they run the long way.